# Booking system using external API

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, products

I am trying to create a site on which you can book certain assets.

The assets themselves, and the times they are available will be fetched from an external API.
The assets will be imported once a week, but the times will have to be fetched at request time, to make sure the information is not stale.

My question is: How should I go about this?

- Should each booking time be a product in itself, and thereby creating a new product each time a booking is bought (I'm guessing no)
- Should I make a configurable product somehow? (I'm guessing yes). If so, is there a way to limit the configuration to show only the free times?

And finally, which events should I hook into in order to double check that the time is free when the product is put in the cart and once again when it is just about to be purchased?

For information I'm currently working on 1.9.0.1

Thank you

Comment: Option 2 sounds fine, please check this booking extension, can help you in the solution, http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bookings-reservations.html

Comment: Did you manage to get your issue resolved?

Comment: Not in a satisfactory way, no.

Comment: Since only one answer was provided, do you have extra information to add to your question to get more answers? Perhaps on what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Doing this yourself in Magento is possible but would require a lot of modifications. Too much to go into in one answer and it would also depend on the needs for the project in the front end.

How ever there are already a couple of ready to go modules

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/booking-and-reservations-by-aheadworks.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bookings-reservations.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/booking-and-reservation-system.html

I would suggest with using any of those. I've used the one from Aheadworks  which worked pretty well for me.